# Total number of paths of length $2$ in a graph that does not have any $4$-cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I know that the total number of paths of length $2$ is just $\sum_{v \in V}{d(v) \choose 2}$ when the degree $d(v)$ of each vertex is $\leq 2$: the reasoning is that each vertex can act as an intermediary vertex, and we are counting the number of ways of choosing the in and out edge for the vertex. But what I don't understand is that if the given graph $G$ does not contain any $4$-cycles, then why is $\sum_{v \in V}{d(v) \choose 2} \leq {|V| \choose 2}$? Sure the fact that there are no $4$-cycles means that $K_{2, 2}$ is not a subgraph. But what does this have to do with counting the number of ways of choosing two vertices of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $v$, we can consider summing $d(v)\choose 2$ as counting $d(v)\choose 2$ pairs of $p,q\in N(v)$, where there exist edges $(p,v),(q,v)$. We show that these pair $(p,q)$s cannot coincide. If $(p,q)$ appears twice when we consider node $v_1$ and $v_2$, $p- v_1-q-v_2-p$ is a $4$-cycle. The total number of such pairs is $|V| \choose 2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the "total number of such pairs" means? The total number of origin and destination nodes in the graph? Or is it so that the ${|V| \choose 2}$ represents the total number of $v_1, v_2$ pairs in which any $(p, q)$ can only appear once?

Comment: It's the number of unordered pairs $p,\ q$. If at most one intermediate vertex can occur between any $p$ and $q$, then the number of $p,\ q$ pairs is an upper bound on the number of paths of length $2$.